# преобразование argument** в const argument**

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, const, передача-параметров

вызов функции:

```
 print2DimensionalArr(recoveryPoints, Nd.vNumber, Nd.uNumber);
```

инициализация массива:

```
Point** recoveryPoints = new Point * [Nd.vNumber];
```

Point - класс(трехмерный вектор)

функция:

```
void print2DimensionalArr (const Point** Arr, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            std::cout << i << ',' << j << '\n' << Arr[i][j];
}
```

перегруженный оператор:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Point& p)
{
    return out << p.x << ';' << p.y << ';' << p.z << '\n';
}
```

Ошибка:
error C2664: "void print2DimensionalArr(const Point **,int,int)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "Point **" в "const Point **".

Вопрос: какого же черта VS лезет куда не надо и какого черта вообще собрался преобразовывать переменные, которые я передаю в функцию? Ведь модификатор const формальных параметров функции никак не может влиять на передаваемый аргумент, а лишь означает что я не имею права менять этот параметр (в случает передачи по ссылке/указателю).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На первый взгляд кажется, что const имеет свойство "расползаться по коду" (обычная проблема), но это не везде работает.

нужно просто добавить чуточку const

```
void print2DimensionalArr (const Point * const * Arr, int n, int m)
```

а некоторые ([east/west const](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2018/11/23/join-the-east-const-revolution/) ) могут сказать, что ещё лучше написать так

```
void print2DimensionalArr ( Point const * const* Arr, int n, int m)
```